# Keep UIWindow size after setting it's UIScreen value

Tags: uiwindow, airplay, uiscreen

I'm using AirPlay, the primary content of the iPad is beamed to the AppleTV fine.

When I want different information on the iPad than is on the AppleTV, I'm getting resolution issues.

I instantiate the UIWindow:

```
_atvWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2048, 1536)];
```

*NSLog indicates the window is the frame size I want*

I set the UIWindow to the iPad screen

```
_atvWindow.screen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0];
```

*NSLog indicates the window frame is now 1024x768*

It's a retina iPad. I want the size to remain retina and the set images accordingly. Once I add retina quality images they are (as you'd expect) way too big. Any ideas what's causing this or what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read the frame size from the screen which comes in your [notification object] object?

```
- (void)handleConnectedScreen:(UIScreen *)screen withViewController:(UIViewController *)controller {
    if(!_airPlayWindow)
    {
        CGRect frame = screen.bounds;
        _airPlayWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        _airPlayWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [_airPlayWindow setScreen:screen];
        _airPlayWindow.hidden = NO;
    }

    UIViewController *oldController = _airPlayWindow.rootViewController;
    [_airPlayWindow setRootViewController:controller];
    [oldController removeFromParentViewController];
}


- (void)screenDidConnect:(NSNotification *)notification {
    ABOutputViewController *c = [[ABOutputViewController alloc] init];
    [self handleConnectedScreen:[notification object] withViewController:c];
}


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenDidConnect:) name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];
```